# how to "overwrite-merge" a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large, multindex (two levels of datetimes)  dataframe.

I have a collection of small dataframes with data. Each dataframe represents a (unique) slice of the main dataframe index.

I want to get that data copied into the main dataframe.  There shouldn't be clashes as each small dataframe is a unique slice of the index.

`pd.DataFrame.merge` and `pd.DataFrame.join` aren't what i'm looking for -- they will want to make new columns.

I made a tiny toy example below.  What I want is the data (column `foo`) in `dfa` and `dfb` to overwrite the `None` in `df` where the indices overlap.

```
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-1-1', end = '2010-12-31', freq='m')
dt2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-1-1', end = '2011-1-10', freq='d')
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dt,dt2], names=['assessment_date', 'contract_date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=mi)
df['foo']=None


dta1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-1-1', end = '2010-2-1', freq='m')
dta2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-1-1', end = '2011-1-5', freq='d')
mia = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dta1,dta2], names=['assessment_date', 'contract_date'])
dfa = pd.DataFrame(index=mia)
dfa['foo']="dfa"


dtb1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-4-1', end = '2010-5-1', freq='m')
dtb2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-1-9', end = '2011-1-12', freq='d')
mib = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dtb1,dtb2], names=['assessment_date', 'contract_date'])
dfb = pd.DataFrame(index=mib)
dfb['foo']="dfb"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by same values of `MultiIndex` by [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat([dfa, dfb])
df2 = df2.reindex(df.index.intersection(df2.index))
df3 = df.combine_first(df2)
```

With your data:

```
df2 = pd.concat([dfa, dfb])
print (df2)
                               foo
assessment_date contract_date     
2010-01-31      2011-01-01     dfa
                2011-01-02     dfa
                2011-01-03     dfa
                2011-01-04     dfa
                2011-01-05     dfa
2010-04-30      2011-01-09     dfb
                2011-01-10     dfb
                2011-01-11     dfb
                2011-01-12     dfb

df2 = df2.reindex(df.index.intersection(df2.index))
print (df2)
                               foo
assessment_date contract_date     
2010-01-31      2011-01-01     dfa
                2011-01-02     dfa
                2011-01-03     dfa
                2011-01-04     dfa
                2011-01-05     dfa
2010-04-30      2011-01-09     dfb
                2011-01-10     dfb

df1 = df.combine_first(df2)
```

---

```
print (df1.head(41))

                               foo
assessment_date contract_date     
2010-01-31      2011-01-01     dfa
                2011-01-02     dfa
                2011-01-03     dfa
                2011-01-04     dfa
                2011-01-05     dfa
                2011-01-06     NaN
                2011-01-07     NaN
                2011-01-08     NaN
                2011-01-09     NaN
                2011-01-10     NaN
2010-02-28      2011-01-01     NaN
                2011-01-02     NaN
                2011-01-03     NaN
                2011-01-04     NaN
                2011-01-05     NaN
                2011-01-06     NaN
                2011-01-07     NaN
                2011-01-08     NaN
                2011-01-09     NaN
                2011-01-10     NaN
2010-03-31      2011-01-01     NaN
                2011-01-02     NaN
                2011-01-03     NaN
                2011-01-04     NaN
                2011-01-05     NaN
                2011-01-06     NaN
                2011-01-07     NaN
                2011-01-08     NaN
                2011-01-09     NaN
                2011-01-10     NaN
2010-04-30      2011-01-01     NaN
                2011-01-02     NaN
                2011-01-03     NaN
                2011-01-04     NaN
                2011-01-05     NaN
                2011-01-06     NaN
                2011-01-07     NaN
                2011-01-08     NaN
                2011-01-09     dfb
                2011-01-10     dfb
2010-05-31      2011-01-01     NaN
```